# How to use rebol/red bind to pass a block argument to another function?

Tags: rebol, red

I don't really understand if it can be done with bind or anything else, the documentation http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wbind.html doesn't help as for me. I want to pass block argument from f2 to f1 :

```
  f1: func[block][
    foreach b block [
      print b
    ]
  ]

  f2: func[][
    a: 1
    b: 2
    block: [a b]
    f1 block
  ]
```

When calling

```
 f2
```

It prints out

```
 a
 b
```

How to make it print out

```
 1
 2
```

while passing [a b] (I don't want to pass [1 2] since it can change all the time and that is not elegant) ? Is it possible with bind or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1: func[block /local i][
    foreach i block [
      print get i
    ]
]
```

or

```
f1: func[block /local b][
    foreach b reduce block [
       print  b
    ]
]
```

There is a need for the local word in Red, as the foreach variable word in Red is not local to the foreach loop.

Comment: Use `function` constructor in Red and you won't need to declare the local word.